# No overload for method 'GetKennel' takes 1 arguments c#

Tags: c#, arguments, overloading

Just getting to grips with fundimentals of c# so I apologise in advance if this is an easy fix/not explained properly

Story aim: Make a UI that connects info from sql

Problem: Error as title states, tried everything to my knowledge to try and fix it, get around it, etc.

What I want to do is show the results of the kennel in the UI panel when the user selects 'view kennel'

in theory it should look like this:

Kennel name [txtbox "example"]
Address1 [txtbox "Example"]
etc etc...

```
 private void **Kennel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)**    <-------Error
{
  DataTable dt = _kennelDAL.GetKennel(_kennelDAL);
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
    txtKennelName.Text = row["Name"].ToString();
    txtAddress1.Text = row["Address1"].ToString();
    txtAddress2.Text = row["Address2"].ToString();
    txtAddress3.Text = row["Address3"].ToString();
    txtPostcode.Text = row["Postcode"].ToString();
    txtCapacity.Text = row["Capacity"].ToString();

  }
}
```

This codes definition comes from...

```
    public DataTable GetKennel(string name, string address1, string address2, string address3,string postcode, int capacity)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //Code here
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[Kennel_SelectByID]", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kennel_Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kennel_Address1", address1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kennel_Address2", address2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kennel_Address3", address3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kennel_postcode", postcode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kennel_capacity", capacity);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
```

Again apologies if there is problems with this question, just been stuck on this for a good while! 
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use

```
DataTable dt = _kennelDAL.GetKennel("MyName", "MyAddress1", "MyAddress2", "MyAddress3", "MyPostCode", 10);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but then when starting the UI it comes up with:

Comment: SqlException was unhandled, procedure or function kennel_selectbyID hass too many arguments specified.

Comment: @PhilipGullick, that's a brand new question, please don't tag this onto your current question and also this indicates a problem in your stored procedure `[Kennel_SelectByID]`. You are giving it too many arguments. Post a new question with the above code and the code of your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable dt = _kennelDAL.GetKennel(_kennelDAL);`

You are calling it with one parameter, whatever `_kennelDAL` is.

However, you have defined this method as having several parameters:

```
public DataTable GetKennel(string name, string address1, string address2, string address3,string postcode, int capacity)
```

You must pass them in (i.e, physically *give* it the *name*, *address* etc), or create an overload that accepts whatever `_kennelDAL` is.

Answer (score 0):

The error states exactly the problem:

You have a method that - in your case - expects six parameters, but you only call it with one (`_kennelDAL`).

Your call should probably look more like this:

```
DataTable dt = _kennelDAL.GetKennel(textBoxName.Text, textBoxAddress1.Text,
                                    textBoxAddress2.Text, textBoxPostCode.Text
                                    textBoxCapacity.Text);
```